# Integrate Sitelink using php

Tags: php

I want to integrate Sitelink with my website using php. For demo they have just provided this code

```
    echo '<p>Testing SiteLink...</p>';
    define( 'SITELINK_URL', "https://www.smdservers.net/CCWs_3.5/CallCenterWs.asmx?WSDL");
    define( 'SITELINK_CORP_CODE', "CCTST" );
    define( 'SITELINK_LOC_CODE', "Demo" );
    define( 'SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN', "Administrator" );
    define( 'SITELINK_CORP_PASS', "Demo" );
    $client = new SoapClient( SITELINK_URL );
    $params->sCorpCode = SITELINK_CORP_CODE;
    $params->sLocationCode = SITELINK_LOC_CODE;
    $params->sCorpUserName = SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN;
    $params->sCorpPassword = SITELINK_CORP_PASS;
    try
    {
    $units = $client->SiteInformation( $params );
    $result = $units->SiteInformationResult;
    }
    catch (Exception $e )
    {
    die( 'Error: '.$e->getMessage().'<br>'.$e );
    }
    echo htmlentities( $result->any );
```

But I am not able to understand how to fecth the data and process it using php. I have to Fetch unit sizes and their respective prices. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not trying to get Units you are getting `SiteInformation`

add type for `$params` first:

```
$params = new stdClass; // as stdClass
$params->sCorpCode = SITELINK_CORP_CODE;
$params->sLocationCode = SITELINK_LOC_CODE;
$params->sCorpUserName = SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN;
$params->sCorpPassword = SITELINK_CORP_PASS;
```

then:

```
$units = $client->UnitTypePriceList($params);
$result = $units->UnitTypePriceListResult->any;
```

and you have to parse the data with `DOMDocument`, check the tag name you want to display and print it out:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($result);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$el = $xpath->query('//Table');

foreach($el as $units){
    $UnitID = $xpath->query('UnitID_FirstAvailable', $units)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $UnitID;
}
```

I don't know what are your desired values, but I took `UnitID_FirstAvailable` as example.

Comment: Thanks Mihia for your reply. Actually I want to fetch the Unit Sizes & Prices, Description, Rate, Special, Rate with Special etc. Please see this link for example. http://www.storquest.com/self_storage/Glendale_AZ/zip_85308/storquest_self_storage/61. You can see the accordian here which displays the above mentioned values.You can also see Online Rate column value which is being crossed out. So are these values fetched from Sitelink or is being calculated on our end in the website. Also can we update the data of Sitelink using API from our website?Thanks

Comment: can I update my sitelink data through API?.And how to make the reservation through API? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`SiteInformation` is expecting array not `Object` and your `$params` was never declared

```
define('SITELINK_URL', "http://www.smdservers.net/CCWs_3.5/CallCenterWs.asmx?WSDL");
define('SITELINK_CORP_CODE', "CCTST");
define('SITELINK_LOC_CODE', "Demo");
define('SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN', "Administrator");
define('SITELINK_CORP_PASS', "Demo");
$client = new SoapClient(SITELINK_URL);
$params = array("sCorpCode" => SITELINK_CORP_CODE,"sLocationCode" => SITELINK_LOC_CODE,"sCorpUserName" => SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN,"sCorpPassword" => SITELINK_CORP_PASS);

try {
    $units = $client->SiteInformation($params);

    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
    print($units->SiteInformationResult->any);

} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br>' . $e);
}
```

[See Live DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PlVNuL)

Comment: I would like to know whether we need to download and Install the Sitelink software or this is clients job? I want to fetch the Unit Sizes & Prices, Description, Rate, Special, Rate with Special etc. Please see this link for example. storquest.com/self_storage/Glendale_AZ/zip_85308/…. You can see the accordian here which displays the above mentioned values.You can also see Online Rate column value which is being crossed out. So are these values fetched from Sitelink or is being calculated on our end in the website. Also can we update the data of Sitelink using API from our website? Thanks

Comment: Hello Baba, I was waiting for your answer. If you get time please reply.I have been searching this for long time but nothing on google nor on the Sitelink site.Also if you could explain the above code. what parameters need to be passed. I have the API PDF.But unable to understand it as no clear instructions are provided in it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rahul Singh .........Juts got back to my system ... but i guess it has be resolved ??

Comment: ..In the API document so many methods are given. I want to fetch all the unit sizes, prices their description etc..How to get that? Also can we update the sitelink data through API? For eg: check this site http://www.coronaselfstoragecenter.com/sl/ How they are pulling up the  unit type, unit size and when a select button is clicked, details of that particular size are displayed. Please help on this. Or please give me your gmail id or skype id so I can explain my problem to you in more detail.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Baba. Also can I update my sitelink data through API?.And how to make the reservation through API?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of old, but I've been doing some extensive work with the API. First off, you'll want this: [SiteLink API Documentation](http://www.sitelink.com/wp-content/themes/sitelink/media/pdf/SiteLink_API.pdf)

To get all available units, you could do something like this:

```
// define API connection credentials
define('SITELINK_URL', "http://www.smdservers.net/CCWs_3.5/CallCenterWs.asmx?WSDL");
define('SITELINK_CORP_CODE', "CCTST");
define('SITELINK_LOC_CODE', "Demo");
define('SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN', "Administrator");
define('SITELINK_CORP_PASS', "Demo");

$client = new SoapClient( SITELINK_URL );
$params->sCorpCode = SITELINK_CORP_CODE;
$params->sLocationCode = SITELINK_LOC_CODE;
$params->sCorpUserName = SITELINK_CORP_LOGIN;
$params->sCorpPassword = SITELINK_CORP_PASS;
$params->lngLastTimePolled = 0;
$params->bTestMode = true;

try
                        {
                        $units = $client->UnitsInformationAvailableUnitsOnly_v2($params);
                        $result = $units->UnitsInformationAvailableUnitsOnly_v2Result;
                        }
                        catch (Exception $e)
                        { 
                        die( 'Error: '.$e->getMessage().'<br />'.$e ); 
                        }
echo '<table>';
                        $formatUnits = new SimpleXMLElement($result->any);
                        foreach($formatUnits->NewDataSet->Table as $unit){
                            echo "<tr>\r\n";
                            echo "<td><a href='#' data-unit-number='".$unit->sUnitName."' data-unit-id='".$unit->UnitID."' data-rate='".$rate."' class='res-unit-link'>".$unit->sUnitName."</a></td>\r\n";
                            echo "<td>".$unit->sTypeName."</td>\r\n";
                            echo "</tr>\r\n";
}
echo '</table>';
```

You could do `var_dump($formatUnits)` to see all available data in the object that gets returned by SiteLink. The above code is an example from something I made where I used jQuery to grab all of the `data-` attributes from the link to use for the rental/reservation process.

I hope this helps somebody. I really could have used it when I first started using the API.